# ASP.NET MVC 4 RedirectToAction doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I created an MVCApplication and it works in a directory on my server like this:

```
 http://www.mywebsite.com/MyApp/
```

When I use `RedirectToAction` like this;

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

It goes to;

```
 http://www.mywebsite.com/Home/Index
```

But I want to redirect to;

```
 http://www.mywebsite.com/MyApp/Home/Index);
```

How can I resolve it?

Edit---

My routeconfig is like this;

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Is the directory set up as an application?

Comment: Can you post the route configuration you have? It should be in Application_Start in Global.asax (or in one of the methods called from there).

Comment: Yes it's an application @Peter

Comment: @TimCopenhaver I added the code to the question.

Comment: Just to be sure you understood what @Peter asked: in IIS you have a *Web Site* with bindings for `www.mywebsite.com` and under that you have an *Application* named *MyApp* running your code?

Answer (score -1):

These redirects follow your route configuration. The default route is {siteUrl}/{controller}/{action}, which is why when you give it the "Index" action and the "Home" controller, you get the URL you're seeing.

You need to specify a new route similar to this:

```
MapRoute("CustomRoute", "MyApp/{controller}/{action}";
```

You can then redirect to it like this:

```
RedirectToRoute("CustomRoute", new {Controller = "Home", Action = "Index" });
```

**EDIT to clarify for the comments -**

It is also possible to solve this using IIS to make MyApp an application. This is the right solution *only if* MyApp is the only value you ever want at the beginning of your route for this site. If, for example, you sometimes need MyApp/{controller}/{action} and other times you need OtherSubfolder/{controller}/{action}, you need to use the routes as I have outlined above (or use areas) instead of just updating IIS.

I am assuming you want the solution using MVC, so that is what is here, but you should also consider the IIS application if that's the right solution for you.

Comment: How can I force to use this route?

Comment: Something else is going on, his existing route config should work.

Comment: This is a hack and only bandaids a lower level issue (which sounds like it's not setup properly in IIS).

Comment: Adding custom routes is not a band-aid hack...it's built for exactly scenarios like this, where you want your route to be custom. Also, adding a site in IIS does not give you the same behavior as configuring a route - it is another way to solve this problem, but it's not necessarily the "right" way. You have to understand what you're doing.

Comment: @ErdinçÖzdemir you tell it which route to use by calling RedirectToRoute instead of RedirectToAction. I updated the answer.

Comment: Just a bit of advice... never name your routes. The above `RedirectToRoute` code should work when using `null` in place of `"Custom Route"`. I also agree that you should always use `RedirectToRoute`, and avoid `RedirectToAction`.

Comment: @TimCopenhaver - in this case, yes, it's a hack.. MVC should know that it's running in an application subfolder and automatically route itself correctly and build routes based on that.  Creating a custom route to overcome a configuration issue is a hack.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I believe the RedirectToRoute feature in MVC was built for exactly this use case. If you believe this is a hack, can you think of any valid (not-hacky) use case for this functionality? All that to say, while it might not seem like great design, I believe Microsoft designers disagree and designed it to work this way intentionally.

Comment: @TimCopenhaver - You believe wrong.  MVC is designed to handle this use case automatically, what you are doing is using a different feature for the wrong purpose.  Either you don't understand the question, or you don't understand how Application root folders and appdomains work.  You are not *supposed* to define a custom route for your application root, otherwise a whole slew of features in MVC don't work correctly.

Comment: As I mentioned within my answer, I am assuming this is NOT defining the actual "application root" but sub-routes under the application root. If you are writing a simple application and need to just define the application root, you do that in IIS - I am completely in agreement on that point, which I believe my answer already explains. This functionality is useful (and not at all hacky) for cases where you want to define different sub-routes within an application.